# Вывод картинок из переменной php

Tags: php

Как вывести картинку на php, не имея ее на диске? Т.е. в переменной (двоичные данные). Просто картинки хранятся в БД и на диск незачем их записывать.

Пробовал:

```
...//другой код
header("Content-type: image/jpeg"); 
echo $content_image;
...//другой код
```

Но это выводит только картинку на весь экран. Как быть?

П.С. Знаю, что хранить картинки в БД, не очень хорошо.

Comment: Сорри за оффтоп... А хостер вас еще не "заказал" за то, что в БД храните изображения? ))) Ну, я еще пойму, если вы используете Оракл, но что-то мне подсказывает, что это просто Мускул.

Comment: Не знаю как в MySQL (вроде бы нет), но PostgreSQL хранит содержимое больших блобов отдельно, используя [TOAST](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/storage-toast.html), а так же реализует такую штуку, как [pg_largeobject](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/largeobjects.html).

Правда, производительность, по сравнению с файловой системой, все равно страдает. Не рекомендовал бы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все верно, у вас картинка выводится при обращении к определенному url, например `img.php?id=asdfgh`. Тогда если в html написать

```
<img src="img.php?id=asdfgh" />
```

выведется картинка. А если вы напишите в адресной строке http://site.com/img.php?id=asdfgh выведется картинка на весь экран.

Comment: А что за img.php??? Мне в нем поключаться к БД и передавать через хидер изображение? Тогда оно будет нормально выводится?

Comment: Да, этот php (это может быть и ваш index.php, например) на запрос картинки подключится к бд, вытащит оттуда картинку с id='asdfg' выдаст картинку. На другой запрос может быть выдан html...

Comment: Спасибо. Все заработало)

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, может вы еще подскажите как решить проблему, ибо не хочется отдельную тему создавать. При переносе вылез "косяк" - где-то вначале файла выводится некий символ/текст, поэтому картинку уже не хочет. Пробовал    <?header("Content-type: image/jpeg"); ...остальной код?> Т.е. даже без пробелов...

Comment: Сложно сказать без кода. Попробуйте локализовать эти дополнительные символы, комментируя разные участки кода...

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы не выводило картинку на весь экран, задавайте ширину и высоту стандартную или вытаскивайте эти данные с самой картинки.

```
<img src="img.php?id=asdfgh" widht="200px" height="200px"/>
```

Comment: проблема не в том, что картинка на весь экран, а в том, что кроме нее ничего не выводилось...